# How to compare server hard drives?

Tags: hardware, hard-drive

What are the metrics and their priorities to compare various hard drives and their accessories for servers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The metrics:

- Drive type: SSD or conventional hard disk
- Drive connection type: SATA vs. SAS nowadays, maybe FC?
- Capacity
- Rot. speed 5500/7200/10000/15000 RPM
- seek time (is more or less dependent on rot. speed)
- Cost/GB

Not sure what you mean by accessories, though, so some guesses:

- Hot swap case for drives
- RAID controller
- RAID box (i.e. 16disk SATA->FC etc).

Priorities are totally dependent on what you need the server to do and what your budget is.

I.e. if you just need a box to dump files on, without the need for zero downtime and high speeds, you could use server class SATA drives and a software RAID, but if you have a medium-sized database where you need extremely fast query times, you might use a fast SSD drive. So please tell us what you want to do so you can get more helpful infos.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I'm going to host websites and need zero downtime. I can't choose between 4x 120gb SSD and 4x 300gb SAS drives. Capacity doesn't matter since I have a seperated storage layer. I have heard SSDs aren't reliable for a server. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are many comparison factors such as:

1- Speed / RPM.

2- HD drive is hot-swappable or not.

3- Capacity.

4- Form factor.

5- Interface.

6- Power consumption.

7- Cost.

The priority depends mainly on your needs / requirements.

Comment: Thanks for answer. For my specific needs, reliability matters.